# How to understand a specific bit of Wordpress syntax

Tags: themes, theme-options

I am changing a theme in Wordpress, and in an earlier theme, there was something like this that added a an email signup widget to the page:

```
[green_tick_1_list width="100%"]
```

But in the new theme that I installed, this just shows up as text. Is there any way to make it show up as the email signup form like it used to?

And what is that syntax? Is that something I can create in WordPress per each theme I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a [Shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).

It may be possible to find the function that renders that shortcode and copy/paste it into [your own plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin), making it theme-independent, however, how easy that will be to do depends on how the shortcode works- if it depends on additional php functions, JavaScript, and CSS embedded within the theme.

Comment: Thank you! So creating a shortcode involved actually adding a .php function to the code? There is no way to do this another way without editing actual code?

Comment: If you want to re-enable that shortcode in another theme, there's unfortunately no way to do it without getting into the old theme's code.